# Typeorm migration with bi-directional manytomany resulting in TypeError: Class exends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a nestjs project with TypeORM. I'm setting up a bidirectional ManyToMany relationship between two entities: Notes and Gcalevents. Every Note could be linked to multiple Gcalevents, and every Gcalevent could be linked to many Notes.

Snippets from my entity definitions look like this:

base.entity.ts:

```
export class BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
    isActive: boolean;
 ... // some more fields
}
```

note.entity.ts:

```
import { Gcalevent } from './gcalevent.entity';
import { BaseEntity } from './base.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'note' })
export class Note extends BaseEntity {

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
    title: string;
...

    @ManyToMany(() => Gcalevent, (gcalevent) => gcalevent.notes)
    @JoinTable()
    gcalevents: Gcalevent[]
}
```

gcalevent.entity.ts:

```
import { Note } from "./note.entity";

@Entity({ name: 'gcalevent' })
export class Gcalevent {  
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') 
    id: string;  

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        nullable: false,
    })
    eventId: string;
...
    @ManyToMany(() => Note, (note) => note.gcalevents)
    notes: Note[]
}
```

I believe I'm declaring the ManyToMany relationships correctly, but when I try to generate the TypeORM migration, I get the error `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`, which points to both the note.entity and gcalevent.entity files

I'm guessing this has something to do with the gcalevent.entity and note.entity files importing each other, combined with the note.entity file importing BaseEntity, but not sure how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've found [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4190)
this "workaround" for the issue.
Try using "strings" instead of "types" in the @ManyToMany decorator:

note.entity.ts:

```
import { Gcalevent } from './gcalevent.entity';
import { BaseEntity } from './base.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'note' })
export class Note extends BaseEntity {

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
    title: string;
...

    @ManyToMany("Gcalevent","notes")
    @JoinTable()
    gcalevents: Gcalevent[]
}
```

gcalevent.entity.ts:

```
import { Note } from "./note.entity";

@Entity({ name: 'gcalevent' })
export class Gcalevent {  
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') 
    id: string;  

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        nullable: false,
    })
    eventId: string;
...
    @ManyToMany("Note","gcalevents")
    notes: Note[]
}
```